# Android toolbar doesn't hide when set layout_scrollFlags

Tags: android, toolbar

I am test android.support.design library,but I have this problem.Please look at follow pictures first.

click the link view the picture:[image: scroll state image]

click the link view the picture:[image: not scroll state image]

You can see it,the toolbar doesn't hide at the back of the status bar.My layout is follow:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".SettingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/action_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can anybody give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I solve the problem. My material test project is create base on the Android Studio IDE default settings. So I check the **values-v21/styles.xml** file. It has a default item `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`. It works fine after I delete the item.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing following changes:

1)
Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from coordinator layout.

2) Cut `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` from `AppBarLayout` and paste it inside `Toolbar`

Comment: I have try the two steps,but it dose not work.Thanks for your concern.

Comment: I will suggest you to follow this tutorial https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

Comment: I have solved the problem,please see my answer.Thank you for your help~

Answer (score 0):

@user5549139 I had the same problem. You shouldn't have deleted

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

It gives you transparent statusBar wchich is coherent with material design.

My problem was that `CordinatorLayout` with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` was included as a child into `DrawerLayout` which also had `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. I removed `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from nested (included) `CoordinatorLayout` and hiding toolbar started to work correctly. I think you have to remove it from Toolbar.